# Anaconda Python, Pyinstaller 3.1.1, script to exe, run time error

Tags: python, compilation, exe, anaconda, python-3.5

Encountered error message "pyi_rth_pkgres.py returns -1" 
when running python script (Python version 3.5.1) to exe in Anaconda 64 environment, compiled (compilation process did not have any errors) by Pyinstaller 3.1.1 as of April 2016.

the scripts uses: 
pandas 0.18 
qt 4.8.7 
qtpy 1.0

Comment: Or, perhaps, you could google `python to exe` or something similar and learn about the many other ways of doing this. I'm willing to bet many of the links point to Stack Overflow, too!

Comment: Perhaps you should try cx_Freeze and py2exe - they're only 1 - 1.5 years old. Make sure you are thoroughly reading the full documentation for each method you try, as well as searching SO and the rest of the web for tips or help with specific errors. If you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then people might be able to help you troubleshoot. As it stands right now, your post is just a rant.

Comment: If you read the documentation it will *tell you* how it works. Yes, you can create executable packages with Anaconda.

Comment: Listen, this is not the site for someone to hold your hand and walk you through all the different methods of doing what you're trying to achieve. You need to get your hands dirty and try some things on your own. Be your own help desk and *learn* how different things work - the internet is vast, and the answers *are* out there if you're willing to look for them, since your case is not the first time anyone has ever tried to do this, believe it or not. Don't just wring your hands and say "*Oh, it's too hard!*" and give up. You've **got** to take some initiative.

Comment: If you have *specific* questions like "*This is my MCVE and here is the full text of the error. I'm trying to do X. Can someone help?*", then we are perfectly willing to help. First, though, please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Feel free to delete the question if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import re

class mainWgt(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        # regex stuff
        rex = re.compile('(?<=ss)\d+')
        match = rex.search('ss23423').group(0)

        # Pandas stuff
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(100, 10))
        self.df[4] = self.df[1] + self.df[2]
        self.df[5] = self.df.apply(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(x[1], x[2]), axis=1)

        # PyQt stuff
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.rootWgt = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.rootWgt)
        self.rootWgt_lay = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.rootWgt)
        self.rootWgt_lay.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.rootWgt)
        self.table.setColumnCount(11)
        self.table.setRowCount(111)

        # all together
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())
        self.table.item(0,0).setText(match)
        for i in self.df:
            for j, item in enumerate(self.df[i]):
                self.table.setItem(j, i, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())
                self.table.item(j, i).setText(str(item))
#} ^ class mainWgt(QtGui.QMainWindow):

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = mainWgt()
gui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is a short sample code involving qtpy and pandas.

I can compile this code with default download from anaconda64 for windows and pycharm community edition, all downloaded on 2016-04-07:

[0] install Anaconda64 for windows without prior install of python. As time of writting, Anaconda by default will install both 3.4.3 and 3.5.1 environment. But that does not cause any grief for me in the following steps.
[1] cmd: pip install pyinstaller, pip install can detect Anaconda's python.
[2] ***revert package "setuptools" to 19.2***. I did that in pycharm (Settings, Project:, Project Interpreter)
[3] follow instructions how to use pyinstaller, everything from here should be google-able

Caveat: the result is a 200MB **3000+** files folder. If you just want a quick exe to do some small chores, stay away from big packages. Pandas is at its best in its scripting form.